# Нарисовать треугольник в Qt3D

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Нашел код, который работает более тесно с OpenGL из Qt3D. Он отрисовывал линию, но я его немнго поменял, чтобы он рисовал треугольники. Когда  я устанавливаю `setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::TriangleStrip);`, то он прекрасно отрисовывает. Но это не то, что мне нужно. Когда я ставлю нужный мне `setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Triangles);`, то не отрисовывается ничего. Может, я неправильные данные в него направляю или не правильно его настроил? (Пример данных внизу)

```
void MainWindow::drawTriangles(const QPolygonF polygon, QColor color, Qt3DCore::QEntity *_rootEntity)
{
    int numOfVertices = polygon.size();
    auto *geometry = new Qt3DRender::QGeometry(_rootEntity);

    // Создаем и заполняем вершинный буфер
    QByteArray bufferBytes;
    bufferBytes.resize(3 * numOfVertices * static_cast<int>(sizeof(float)));
    float *positions = reinterpret_cast<float*>(bufferBytes.data());

    for(auto point : polygon){
        float fHalfMapWidth = (dFittedMaxMapX_ - dFittedMinMapX_) / 2;
        float fHalfMapHeight = (dFittedMaxMapY_ - dFittedMinMapY_) / 2;

        *positions++ = static_cast<float>(point.x() - (dFittedMinMapX_ + fHalfMapWidth));
        *positions++ = 0.0f; //We need to drow only on the surface
        *positions++ = static_cast<float>(point.y() - (dFittedMinMapY_ + fHalfMapHeight));
    }

    auto *buf = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry);
    buf->setData(bufferBytes);

    auto *positionAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry); // Создаем вертексный атрибут
    positionAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());
    positionAttribute->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float); //В буфере у нас будут флоаты
    positionAttribute->setVertexSize(3); // Размер одной вершины
    positionAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute); // Тип атрибута
    positionAttribute->setBuffer(buf); // Сам буфер
    positionAttribute->setByteStride(3 * sizeof(float)); // Шаг между вершинами
    geometry->addAttribute(positionAttribute); // Добавляем атрибут в наш Qt3DRender::QGeometry

    // Создаем и заполняем индексный буфер
    QByteArray indexBytes;
    indexBytes.resize(numOfVertices * static_cast<int>(sizeof(unsigned int))); // start to end
    unsigned int *indices = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(indexBytes.data());
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < static_cast<unsigned int>(numOfVertices); ++i) {
        *indices++ = i;
    }

    auto *indexBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry);
    indexBuffer->setData(indexBytes);

    auto *indexAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry); // Создаем индексный атрибут
    indexAttribute->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::UnsignedInt); // Тип данных в индексном буфере
    indexAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::IndexAttribute); // Тип атрибута
    indexAttribute->setBuffer(indexBuffer); // Сам индексный буфер
    indexAttribute->setCount(static_cast<unsigned int>(numOfVertices)); // Количество вершин, как я понял
    geometry->addAttribute(indexAttribute); // Добавляем атрибут в наш Qt3DRender::QGeometry


    auto *poly = new Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer(_rootEntity);
    poly->setGeometry(geometry); // Устанавливаем нашу геометрию
    //poly->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::TriangleStrip); - Рабочий варииант
    poly->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Triangles); // - Почему-то не выводит ничего

    //Создаем материал
    auto *material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(_rootEntity);
    material->setAmbient(color);

    auto *trianglesEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(_rootEntity);
    trianglesEntity->addComponent(poly); // Добавляем наш рисунок
    trianglesEntity->addComponent(material); // Добавляем наш материал
}
```

Пробовал и три точки и четыре. С четырьмя получается только с TriangleStrip. С Triangles не получается в обоих случаях.

```
mapBorder << QPointF(300,200) << QPointF(100,200) << QPointF(200,0) << QPointF(300,200) << QPointF(200,0) << QPointF(500,200) << QPointF(500,300); 
drawTriangles(mapBorder, QColor(Qt::black), mapEntity_);
```

Answer (score 1):

На английском стаковерфлоу подсказали. Для треугольника необходимо и достаточно только 3 вершины. У меня не было отрисовки в режиме Triangles, потому что по-умолчанию отрисовка примитивов происходит по часовой стрелки, а я давал на вход вершины в обратном порядке. Если изменить их порядок на "по часовой стрелке", то все начинает отрисовываться. Чтобы изменить это поведение на отрисовку обратного порядка или для отрисовки обоих порядков можно использовать https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qt3drender-qcullface.html#details
Я до конца не понимаю, как это правильно указывать, но сделал кривую реализацию, основываясь на коде из ответа отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818584/2d-meshes-in-qt3d